# MySQL query is executing one 'if' statement but not the second

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which allows users to upload their personal details and details about their investments into a MySQL database. The queries all work fine on their own but I am having trouble when wrapping them in if statements. It appears that the first if statement (i.e. the one which appears first in the script) works but the second one does not work (i.e. the values are not inputted into the database). I have tried swapping them round and, sure enough, the first one works but the second doesn't.

I have tried everything I can think of (putting them both in one statement, connecting to the database only once, etc etc etc) but I have only posted my latest attempt because I know this one works if the order is changed.

Code is as follows:

```
if(($m1!==""))
{
echo "m1 is set";
$con=mysqli_connect("ip","username","password","db_name");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products_singles(idsingleclient,productname,value,platform,risk)
VALUES ('$clientid','$m1','$m2','$m3','$m4')");

}
else{echo"";}

if(($l1!==""))
{
echo"l1 is set";
$con=mysqli_connect("ip","username","password","db_name");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products_singles (idsingleclient, productname, value, platform, risk)
VALUES ('$clientid','$l1','$l2','$l3', '$l4')");

mysqli_close($con);

}
else {echo"";}
```

Can anyone suggest anything? Basically the first 'if' statement inserts values as it should but the second is ignored completely (no null values in the database or anything).

Comment: What is the value of `$l1` and all the other variables you use in the second query?

Comment: Is "l1 is set" printed out when you run this? Also you should wrap mysqli_connect() and mysqli_query() with if-statements to catch errors.

Comment: $l1 = ISA, $l2 = 10000, $l3 = fidelity, $l4 = high

Comment: @fluff - yes l1 and m1 are printed out and I do not get any error messages

Comment: @user2491207 - you're not actually checking for errors, though. Add a couple of calls to `mysqli_error()` and see if the database returns any errors.

Comment: @andrewsi - I don't quite know what you mean by this. Can you offer an example of where the checks would fit into my code please?

Comment: Most probably you are trying to insert two rows with the same idsingleclient, which is either primary or unique key. Mysql returns error on second query but you are not checking for errors so it silently fails. If mysqli_query() returns false then print out what mysqli_error() returns.

Comment: @piotrm - that is correct, idsingleclient is set as primary key (not unique key). I need idsingleclient to be the same in different rows because it is all linked to the same client. Is there another way around this? I.e. adding multiple rows for the same client in the same script?

Comment: There can be only one row in a table with given primary key, if you need more rows with the same client id then it shouldn't be a primary key. You need some other unique column set as primary key, if you don't have one then just add psid or sth like that, set it as primary and auto-increment after you change idsingleclient to a simple index.

Comment: That must be it, thank you so much. One last question: idsingleclient is set as the foreign key (to cascade on update and delete), so can it still be the foreign key if it is not the primary key?

Comment: Any indexed column can be set as foreign key.